# Changing html properties after fetching API data in android studio

Tags: android

I'm fetching data using API and the one of the data is a HTML formatted text.

The data fetched from the API

```
{
"id": 4632,
"title": "Soy-and-Ginger-Glazed Salmon with Udon Noodles",
"summary": "Soy-and-Ginger-Glazed Salmon with Udon Noodles might be a good recipe to expand your main course collection. This dairy free and pescatarian recipe serves 4 and costs <b>$5.91 per serving</b>. One serving contains <b>552 calories</b>, <b>48g of protein</b>, and <b>17g of fat</b>. 1 person were impressed by this recipe. From preparation to the plate, this recipe takes roughly <b>1 hour and 35 minutes</b>. This recipe from Food and Wine requires sesame seeds, lime juice, olive oil, and salmon fillets. Taking all factors into account, this recipe <b>earns a spoonacular score of 92%</b>, which is great. If you like this recipe, take a look at these similar recipes: <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/soy-and-ginger-glazed-salmon-with-udon-noodles-1309259\">Soy-and-Ginger-Glazed Salmon with Udon Noodles</a>, <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/soy-and-ginger-glazed-salmon-with-udon-noodles-1360935\">Soy-and-Ginger-Glazed Salmon with Udon Noodles</a>, and <a href=\"https://spoonacular.com/recipes/soy-and-ginger-glazed-salmon-with-udon-noodles-1321839\">Soy-and-Ginger-Glazed Salmon with Udon Noodles</a>."
```

}
The summary is a HTML formatted text and im using `HTML.fromHtml()` to display the displayable styled text. My question is, is it possible to change the properties inside the HTML such as text decoration of a link to another color?

**RecipeDetails.java**

```
private final RecipeDetailsListeners recipeDetailsListeners = new RecipeDetailsListeners() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void didFetch(RecipeDetailsResponse response, String message) {
            Picasso.get().load(response.image).into(recipeImage);
            RecipeName.setText(response.title);
            recipeSource.setText(response.sourceName);
            if (response.sourceName == null){
                recipeSource.setText("Unknown");
            }
            recipeServing.setText(response.servings + " Serving");
            recipeTimePrepared.setText(response.readyInMinutes + " Min");
            recipeScore.setText(String.valueOf(response.aggregateLikes) + " Likes");
            recipeSummary.setText(Html.fromHtml(response.summary, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

            IngredientListRecipeDetails.setHasFixedSize(true);
            IngredientListRecipeDetails.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false ));
            adapter = new recipeDetailsIngredientAdapter(getBaseContext(), response.extendedIngredients);
            IngredientListRecipeDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void didError(String message) {
            customToast("Unsuccessful", message, "Failure");
        }
    };
```

Comment: You're getting raw html and displaying it.  You can change that string before calling HTML.fromHtml and do whatever you want with it.  Now doing so would probably require you to write or find an HTML tokenizer, so it's going to be a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: Html formatted? I see only bold tags. There are no links so how would you change links?

Comment: @blackapps i've edit the code, there's some item without the link tag on them

Comment: Can you pos the stuff in such a way that we dont have to scroll horizontally half an hour?